# Formato no deseado en parametro Datetime (Procedimiento almacenado)

Tags: sql, datetime

Construí un `procedimiento almacenado` que tiene dos parámetros tipo **fecha**. El problema es que dichas fechas me llegan con formato

> NombreMes Día Año Hora:Minuto AM

por ejemplo si le envío la fecha `'2017-02-05'` llega al procedimiento como `Feb 05 2017 12:00AM`.

Lo que necesito es convertir dicha fecha en un formato `yyyyMMdd`; traté con `CONVERT` de la siguiente forma:

```
Convert(datetime, fecha, 112)
```

Sin resultado alguno.

Cabe mencionar que la funcion `FORMAT` no es soportada por la versión SQL del servidor (**SQLServer 2008**)

Cualquier información se agradece

Comment: Disculpa es la costumbre de llamarlo así... `stored procedure`, lo edito para que se entienda mejor :)

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que tienes un sp, con parámetros tipo `datetime`, pero quién lo invoca le pasa las fechas como cadenas con un determinado formato. Esto efectivamente es así?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho cuando realizo la condicional `WHERE` debo convertir los parametros a numeros para que me quede un formato `yyyMMdd`... probé convirtiendo primero a `VARCHAR` y después a `INT`, casteando, creando variables y hasta ahora nada =/

Comment: Paulo, el tema es que un DATETIME no tiene ningún formato específico , el formato recién aparece cuando conviertes un DATETIME a un VARCHAR por ejemplo. Tal como mencionas, un `Convert(datetime, fecha, 112)` si y únicamente si, `fecha` es un DATETIME, te devolverá una cadena en formato YYYYMMDD. Si en las tablas, las fechas se guardan como un entero, lo único que se me ocurre que te podría estar faltando es hacer `Convert(INT,Convert(datetime, fecha, 112))`. ¿Que resultado obtienes al hacer `Convert(datetime, fecha, 112)`? o más bien  que tipo de dato es `fecha`?

Comment: Y por último ¿Que tipo de dato es la columna de la tabla que usas en el WHERE?

Comment: Patricio.. tanto los parametros que le envio como la columna del WHERE son datetimes; lo raro es que al imprimir los parametros sin realizar ningun convert me lanza ese formato que mencione en la pregunta

Comment: Para mostrarte los datos ,como los tiene que imprimir como una cadena los formatea de alguna forma. Si ambos son DATETIME, no hace falta que hagas ninguna conversión en el WHERE, simplemente `WHERE fecha = parametro_sp_fecha`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente solucioné el envío de los parámetros desde mi código en `C#` enviando sólo la fecha de esta forma

```
DateTime.Parse(item.Start.ToString()).Date)
```

Lo único que se me ocurre del porqué no funciono con ninguna conversión es la versión que estoy utilizando de SQL pero sinceramente ni a mi me convence este argumento.

Agradecido por la disposición!